# Validating using while loop, how do I make it look like an error

Tags: c

I want to make the program to ask user to input correct value, but the while loop prints the error statement even when the user input correct value. How can I solve this?

```
int n, range, i;
printf("Enter an integer to find multiplication table :- \t");
while(i<0)
{
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if(i<0)
    printf("Please enter a positive integer :- \n");
}
```

Comment: remove `;` in `if (i<0);`

Comment: Besides, give an initial (negative) value to i.

Comment: Format your code correctly.

Comment: I restored the buggy `;` ... please don't edit code in questions to include the fixes people have provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize your i value with -1 as it initialize null so you are getting the error message.
so try to run this code.

```
int n, range, i=-1;
printf("Enter an integer to find multiplication table: \t");
while(i<0)
{
      scanf("%d", &i);
      if (i<0)
        printf("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
}
```

sorry in rush I make a mistake.

Comment: this will never enter the loop

Comment: @MattMcNabb sorry in rush i make a mistk and thanks 4 make me correct

Comment: This worked, But I am not sure how it helped by initializing 'i' with a negative value.

Comment: @Muroo First describe what this condition `while(i<0){....}` indicate ? Need to learn basic concept of `C`.

Comment: @Jayesh - Its a while loop, If the condition in the brackets is not met, then the user is made repeat the entries (for this particular piece of codes) until the user enters a value that is in range with the condition. And I just went back to revising. I remember now how it helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Muroo `If the condition in the brackets is not met,....` No..No if it satisfy then it will repeat.

Comment: Was actually trying to say something like that, my bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* err[4]={"please", "!! take care, ","Dude! R u sober?", "C'mon! I say " };
int main()
{
    int i, m=0, flg;
    printf("Enter an integer to find multiplication table: \t");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    while(i<0)
    {
        if(m==4) {flg = 1; break;}
        printf("\n%s enter a positive integer: \n", err[m]);
        scanf("%d", &i);
        m++;
    }

    if(!flg)printf("\n%d\n", i);
    else printf("\nplease consider revising primary school's mathematics");
    return 0;
}
```